# In Openpyxl, how to replace a cell with a Cell object in a worksheet?

Tags: python, openpyxl

So I have a function which takes a `Cell` object and spit out a processed `cell`:

```
from openpyxl.cell.cell import Cell
cell = Cell(ws)

def process_cell(cell):
    # Add style to cell
    return cell
```

However I can't do this:

```
cell = process_cell(cell)
ws['A1'] = cell
```

The error is:

```
raise ValueError("Invalid column index {0}".format(idx))
ValueError: Invalid column index None
```

Comment: Could you not just `process_cell(ws['A1'])`? It should change the `styles` within `ws['A1']` just fine as it's an object reference, not a value.

Comment: It seems you're trying to replace the actual `Cell` object `ws.cell(1,1)` into your processed `cell` object, which I would say is probably the wrong way to go about it.  You'll be replacing all the valuable `cell` attributes with the default `Cell` attributes as you only provided the minimal `worksheet` argument.  The `column`, `row`, `value`... etc attributes will all be empty and therefore the cell is basically wiped with the exception of your explicitly added attributes in `process_cell`.

Comment: You can forcibly replace the `cell` object like this `ws._cells[1, 1] = cell` __but you will end up losing all the information from the existing cell__.  You should just be changing the `ws.cell(1, 1)` object in place instead of assigning a new one.

Comment: Read [cell-styles-and-named-styles](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html#cell-styles-and-named-styles) how to change `cell` styles.

Comment: I'm following an example in the openpyxl tutorial: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pandas.html. In the writeOnlyCell example, it uses a generator to apply the cell style to every cell in the row. It `append` the generator to the worksheet. The worksheet variable `ws` is only provided when the generator is created. And It has no problem appending the row to the worksheet.

Comment: Please provide all the relevant code and the full traceback.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is this: 
`cell = Cell(ws)`

This creates a cell bound to a particular worksheet but without any coordinates which you must supply. If you are in write-only mode then you **must** use a `WriteOnlyCell` and pass this in to the worksheet's `append()` method.

Comment: I tried a regular `Cell` and it works well with `append`. I just can't replace a single cell.